# iOS intercept ASWebAuthenticationSession header during SSO

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, http-headers, single-sign-on

I have a requirement to add some custom header during WebView SSO call using

> ASWebAuthenticationSession

I am looking for some help on how do we intercept the request header on ASWebAuthenticationSession and modify some header objects like `User-Agent, Connection & user_otherdetails` ?

Any suggestion will be much helpful.

Thanks